# using multiple RadioButtons in a recyclerview

Tags: android, radio-button, android-recyclerview

I am making a program in which I want to save which players were in training , just a journal for coaches. So I want to have three Radio buttons in each row of the recyclerview (one for when the player is present, one when he is not and one when he has a reason for not being there).

I want to change the state value in PersonItem to state 1,2 or 3 so I can use it later in the program to save it to a database.

The problem i am having is that the recyclerview does not show up properly and for example when I have two PersonItems shows up like.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////.

PersonItem1.

(RadioButton)present.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////.

PersonItem1.

(RadioButton)present,(RadioButton)absent.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////.

The radio buttons also have weird behavior.

Here is the code:

```
public NewTrainingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PersonItem> feedItemList) {
    this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vrstica_new_training_row, null);

    view.setClickable(true);

    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder,final int i) {
    PersonItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

    customViewHolder.name.setText(feedItem.getName().toString() + " " + feedItem.getLastName().toString());

    setRadio(customViewHolder, 1);



    customViewHolder.present.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            feedItemList.get(i).setState(0);
            setRadio(customViewHolder, feedItemList.get(i).getState());
        }
    });
    customViewHolder.absent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            feedItemList.get(i).setState(0);
            setRadio(customViewHolder, feedItemList.get(i).getState());
        }
    });
    customViewHolder.forgiven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            feedItemList.get(i).setState(0);
            setRadio(customViewHolder, feedItemList.get(i).getState());
        }
    });



}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

private void setRadio(final CustomViewHolder holder, int selection) {

    RadioButton b1 = holder.present;
    RadioButton b2 = holder.absent;
    RadioButton b3 = holder.forgiven;

    if (selection == 0) b1.setChecked(true);

    if (selection == 1) b2.setChecked(true);

    if (selection == 2) b3.setChecked(true);

}



public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected TextView name;
    protected RadioButton present,absent,forgiven;
    protected RadioGroup presence;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlayerName);
        this.presence = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupPlayerInTraining);
        this.present = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonPresent);
        this.absent = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonAbsent);
        this.forgiven = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonForgiven);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (itemClickListener != null) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

also the code in the vrstica_new_training_row is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlayerName" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupPlayerInTraining">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Prisoten"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonPresent"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Odsoten"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonAbsent"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Opravičen"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonForgiven"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what i need to change to make my code work like I want.
Thank you for the answers in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

I see that you do no t have an answer yet. I cannot quite understand your problem yet because I only see "///////" in your results. But, if you are having the same problem as I have which is that RecyclerView's recycling feature is copying my selections into recycled views. An easy way to fix this if your app does not rely much on that feature is setting your RecyclerView views cache to your list size:

```
yourRecyclerView..setItemViewCacheSize(yourItemList.size());
```

Be sure that you update this if the list is changing dynamically...